Finding Thevenin voltage and resistance
I am struggling to find the Thevenin voltage and resistance across terminals A and B of the given circuit.

I got as far as writing KCL at nodes 2 and 3, which gave this:
$$v_\text{AB} = - G_2/G_1 e + \frac{G_1 + G_2}{G_2} e_2$$
$$e_1 = e_2 = e_3$$
From here, I don't really know how to proceed to calculate \$v_\text{AB}\$. I don't even know how to start calculating \$R_\text{Th}\$.

Please explain why you think nodes 1 and 3 have anything to do with the solution.

I'm sort of a beginner with op amps, why would'nt they have something to do with the solution?

Because it's a trick question. The circuit is a summing amplifier with the question concerning one of the two inputs.

I'm sorry, I'm not following you guys. I should also add that v_AB should equal -e (from the solution manual).

For an ideal op amp, the currents into inverting and non-inverting inputs are zero.

That I get, however, e2 apperars in the KCL at node 2, and the only other equation I could write that gave me some more information about e2 was the KCL at node 3. I don't get why I shouldn't care about nodes 1 and 3...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What I am asking is how to calculate v_AB and R_Th. I'm not looking for a straight up solution, but I don't understand why my calculations are getting me nowhere. What other equations should I write? Is there something crucial that I am missing?

If you remove the op amp from the circuit, how does that change the circuit equivalence at nodes A & B?

What do you mean by "remove"? Does it mean "consider the series of e, R1 and R2"? In that circuit v_AB = e R1/(R1 + R2) which is not the correct result.

No. V_AB = e if opamp is ideal ... and there is no load between A and B.

Ok, but I don't get why that is

All the comments are trying to point out that the op amp is a distraction, i.e., it has no bearing on the question except to confuse you. This assumes that the op amp is ideal which means infinite input impedance (the important parameter for this question), infinite open-loop gain, and infinite bandwidth. For school studies, this is a fair assumption for first level approximations.
Thus, the equivalent circuit is merely:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
By observation you should be able to figure out the Thevinin equivalent circuit from this.
